# React SPA incorporate /register /login and /members routing

Tags: reactjs, routes

i am looking for a clean way to incorporate react routes in my SPA. Its your typical single page app with home, about, members, and contact form. I want to incorporate a signup/signin page in my members area, but i do not want it to be included in my spa. For example my page is on localhost:3000 and the entire page is loaded there, ergo spa. However i want to add the /register, /login and /account paths to direct to other pages and i am in a pickle as to how i will achieve this. I managed to use Routes/Route in react and its loading in the bottom of my page and i cannot understand why!

My imports are correct, i can provide if need be.

Code example:
App:

```
 function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <AuthContextProvider>
        <Navbar />
        <Home />
        <About />
        <Data />
        <Members />
        <Contact />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/signin' element={<Signin />} />
          <Route exactpath='/signup' element={<Signup />} />
          <Route
            path='/account'
            element={
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <Account />
              </ProtectedRoute>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
```

Answer (score 0):

Created an external main.js app and wrapped the spa in it